# How to calculate no of days in xpages

Tags: xpages

I'm one of the naive developer of XPages application. I took up XPages as I find them really interesting to build whatever we want.

Here is one of my problems on which I am working from days but couldn't get over it.

In my Leave application, I have two date fields, leaveFrom & leaveTill and one computed edit box where I would display the no. of days (noDays) dynamically i.e. the difference of above two leave date fields. And 
I am unable to do such a simple thing.

I'm using Lotus 8.5.3 for creating this application. I saw some of the methods like `getcomponent("").setvalue()` or `getvalue()`. But these two methods are not available in 8.5.3. I always get error when I use these methods. I tried using getComponent on CSJS also.. but no success.

I also tried using other script methods, I could get backend documents created but value is not showing on my current xpage.

Please show me the correct path.

Comment: Here is a XSnippet which perhaps helps to calculate the duration in business days: http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=getnextbusinessdayint-offset-date-basedate-int-excludeddaysofweek-string-excludeddatelist

Comment: You say that you get errors using setvalue and getvalue. Are you trying to use these methods on the CLIENT or the SERVER side? If you try to use them clientside you will fail because these methods are SERVERside javascript.

Comment: Thank you Sven. I'm looking at the snippet and try to implement it.

Comment: @ jjtbsomhorst: I tried using them both on Client as well as Server side JS but none of them worked. Am I missing on any software installation?

Comment: Please post your XPages source code.

Comment: Practical joke I heard many times: "Repeat after me - Java si CASE SENSITIVE!". And XPages is Java (and JavaScript, which is case sensitive too).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is not working because the method *timeDifference* did not exists for Java dates:

```
var difference = endDate.timeDifference(startDate);
```

You have to convert it to *NotesDateTime* first:

```
var difference = null; 
try{
    var nDateStart = session.createDateTime( startDate );
    var nDateEnd = session.createDateTime( endDate );

    difference = nDateEnd.timeDifference(nDateStart); 
    difference = (Math.floor(difference/86400)) + 1;
}catch(e){return e}

difference
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following XSnippet to compare dates (and thereby also calculate number of days between two dates): http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=compare-dates. I hope yuou can use this as input for your specific case.

With regards to getComponent("").getValue() and .setValue(). They are certainly available in 8.5.3 too. Remember that XPages is case sensitive.

Comment: Thanks Per! I tried using the same code but I encountered this error "getcomponent is not defined". Is any additional s/w required ?

Comment: @Ravi: Try *getComponent* instead of *getcomponent*.

Comment: I tried several codes but here is on what I finally landed up..but still not working:

var startDate = getComponent("leaveReqdFrom1").getValue() ;

var endDate = getComponent("leaveReqdTo1").getValue() ;

var difference = endDate.timeDifference(startDate);

difference = (Math.floor(difference/86400)) + 1;

alert('Button click');

getComponent("noDays1").setValue(difference);

Alert in the above code is also not working.

Comment: Ravi - you're not saying what event this code is going into.  A button?  something else?  For buttons remember there's a Server and Client Tab.  you want this code to be in CLIENT.

Comment: Ravi - Ignore the comment on getComponent.  that IS server side.  But Alert is not.  That's Client Side.

Answer (score 0):

> Thanks to your explanatory videos, I learned a lot from them.

Notes in 9? :)

Back to your question.

If both fields are DATETIME format then you can do something like the following.

```
(endDate - startDate) / (24*60*60);
```

Comment: The main problem I'm getting is to get the value from two dates field. values are not even displaying in alert ! & yes you are correct I learned from NotesIn9

Comment: I encountered this error "getcomponent is not defined". Is any additional s/w required ?

Comment: it's getComponent("elementName").getValue();  . Case sensitive.